# Grouping Drupal Views by field with multiple options - only show one field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, grouping

I am using Drupal 7 and the views module, and would like to return a list of nodes grouped by an options field.  I can get it to do so, but instead of looking like

> Option A
>    node 1
>    node 2
>  Option B
>    node 1
>   
>    node 3
>  Option C
>    node 2
>    node 4

it displays as

> Option A, Option B
>    node 1
>  Option A
>    node 1 
>   node 2
>  Option A, Option C
>    node 2
>  Option B
>   node 1
>    node 3
>  Option C
>    node 2
>    node 4

This gets lengthy after many nodes, and would like to display only single field options.

I have field criteria set as Or [field option]  and grouping set as group [field x]

I cannot find this problem documented anywhere else

Comment: Soooo what i wanted to do was make a view based on term instead of node.

and then the key was: make a relationship in the term view to node and content, and then the fields will be available.

okay, rock on,

Answer (score 3):

http://drupal.org/node/1672606#comment-6202392

Had the same question, solved thanks to nevets...
Just uncheck 'Display all values in the same row' under 'Multiple Field Settings'.